# laravel search input Get instead of Post

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

Blade:

```
<form id="search_field" style="margin: 0; display: none" class="submit_form item" method="post" action="{{route('search')}}">
    <div class="ui icon input">
        <input style="padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <i class="form search link icon"></i>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#search').click(function () {
    $('#search').hide();
    $("#search_field").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
})

$('.form').click(function () {

    $('.submit_form').submit();
})
```

Laravel:

```
Route::post('search', 'SearchController@search')->name('search');
```

So if i'm pressing the icon it goes over the post route.
But if i'm write something in the input and press enter it goes over the get route.

What should i do that it goes in every way over the post route ?

Comment: is there some javascript acting on your webform? if yes please show it and show us the actual route,

Comment: It's not an answer to you question why you get the switch, but why would you want a search to be a `POST`? It is retrieval of data and I would've expected a `GET`. This way you have caching, you can bookmark a search, etc etc. It is generally more fitting to use a `GET` here I believe?

Comment: Yeah you right. I've only used this example cause no of my POST routes work on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I had to implement the `{{ csrf_field() }}` in my form.

```
<form id="search_field" style="margin: 0; display: none" class="submit_form item" method="post" action="{{route('search')}}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="ui icon input">
    <input style="padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <i class="form search link icon"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a get route that is the same URL in your routes/web.php file for that action? The routes are being executed by order from top to bottom, so you must put the post route before the get route.
Like this

```
Route::post('/search', 'yourcontroller@store');
Route::get('/search', 'yourcontroller@index');
```

OR
make sure to capitalize the POST method in your form tag

```
<form id="search_field" style="margin: 0; display: none" class="submit_form item" method="POST" action="{{route('search')}}">
```

Comment: i've only one route for search, and i checked it with capitalize POST but it doesnt work.